# Combinatorics: what is the total number of fermionic microstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, statistics

This might be pretty basic but, say we have a fermionic chain with $L$ sites which can be occupied by one fermion. One possible macrostate is to have 1 fermion in the chain which in turn may be microscopically achieved by $L$ different microstates. In general, the number of microstates of a given macrostate is given by
$$
\#\text{microstates}=\frac{L!}{n!(L-n)!},
$$
where $n$ is the total number of fermions in the macrostate of interest (in the example before: $n=1 \implies \#=L!/1!(L-1)!=L)$. The total number of all possible microstates is ‘simply’ the sum of the number of microstates in all the possible macrostates, that is
$$
\#\text{all microstates}=\sum_{n=0}^L\frac{L!}{n!(L-n)!}.
$$
**Is there a close form for the above summation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $L$ sites, and each of them can be either occupied or empty, the total number of states is
$$
2^L = (1 + 1)^L = \sum_{n=0}^L{L \choose n} 1^n1^{N-n} = \sum_{n=0}^L{L \choose n}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Omg I’m getting worse at this every day...

Comment: Is there a close form when the sum doesn’t run all the way up to $L$, say up to some arbitrary in between integer $k$?

Comment: @FriendlyLagrangian No, not to my knowledge. Although it is easy to calculate for $k=L/2$ (half-filling).

Comment: Im going to edit the question if you dont mind so that becomes the question.